# Tensor in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Consider the equation of  the dielectric tensor $\bar{\epsilon}$ of a [nematic liquid crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal#Nematic_phase) in  flat space in cartesian coordinates,

\begin{equation}
\bar{\epsilon}=\epsilon_{iso}\delta_{ij}+\epsilon_a\left(n_in_j-\frac{\delta_{ij}}{3} \right),
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon_{iso}=\frac{\epsilon_\|+2\epsilon_\bot}{3}$, $\epsilon_a=\epsilon_\|-\epsilon_\bot$,  $\epsilon_\|$ and $\epsilon_\bot$ are  the molecular dielectric constants, respectively, parallel and perpendicular to the major axis of a prolate ellipsoid liquid crystalline molecule, and $n_i$ are the components of the versor $\hat{n}$ (AKA *director*) that gives the average orientation of the major axis of these liquid crystalline molecules.

How can I modify this equation for cylindrical coordinates in flat space? Is it sufficient to consider $\delta_{ij}$  as the metric tensor and to write it in cylindrical coordinates? Or may I multiply $n_in_j$ by $\delta_{ij}$ (imagining a scalar product)? With these suggestions, for example,  I can't obtain the correct dielectric tensor for the director $\hat{n}=\hat{\theta}$. An equivalent formulation of this question: how can I generalize this equation for any coordinates?

Again, please forgive me for this basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\delta_{ij}$ should be interpreted as the metric tensor in Cartesian coordinates.

People on the more pure mathematics side of things tend to write things like this in a basis independent manner.  For any vectors $a, b$,

$$\bar \epsilon(a,b) = \epsilon_\text{iso} (a \cdot b) + \epsilon_a ([\hat n \cdot a][\hat n \cdot b] - \frac{1}{3} a \cdot b)$$

Use whatever basis you like, as long as the inner products (denoted by $\cdot$) transform accordingly, using the corresponding metric.